# Top header: Reduce width of input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using this grid as a top navabar and I want to make a few alterations:

How can I reduce the width of the input to 40% but still keep it right next to the logo? And how can I add a sign-in div at the right hand corner. But keep in mind that I want the entire header to remain responsive like it is now. If I do the following it looks good in  a full screen but when the width of the screen is smaller the input becomes really small.

```css
.top_nav_menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #eeeeee;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin-right: 90px;
  padding: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
}


.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
}

.header > form {
  width: 65%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.header > form > input {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_nav_menu">
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EFkps0m.png">
    <form><input type="text"></form>
    <div class="floar-right">Sign-in</div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either reduce the value of `40%` in your CSS.
Or add new CSS for max-width:

```
.header > form > input {
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

For your sign-in div, you can add this CSS:

```
.float-right {
float:right;
}
```

However your current class spells floar and not float, you should change that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        } 
        .top_nav_menu {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
            box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 #eeeeee;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            background-color: #fafafa;
            margin-right: 90px;
            padding: 15px;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        .header {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            align-items: center;
            height: 50px;
        }
        .header > form {
            width: 65%;
            margin-left: 25px;
        }
        .header > form > input {
            width: 24%;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="top_nav_menu">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/EFkps0m.png">
            <form><input type="text"></form>
            <div class="floar-right">Sign-in</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```